# Can I restore a SQL Server 2008 database into SQL Server 2008 Express?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm moving from a shared hosting company to a dedicated server.  The hosting provider used SQL Server 2008 (not sure if it was Professional or Standard). I've installed SQL Server 2008 Express on the dedicated server.  The hosting company has provided me with backups of our databases.  I'm going to restore these backups into SQL Server 2008 Express.

Is this possible?  Can I restore a SQL Server 2008 database into SQL Server 2008 Express?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, yes. Have a look here for a comparison of the SQL Server 2008 editions:

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions-compare.aspx

Comment: I tried it out last night and I was able to restore without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can restore, as long as the source database is not using any of the Enterprise/Standard Only features [like Compression]